# Find and click an element by title using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking site. In the inspect element, see this:

```html
<span id="item60" title="Havai 30" class="item button link">Get</span>
<span id="item90" title="Classic 50" class="item button link">Get</span>
```

I need to get and click an element by title. Something like this:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="item60"]').click()
```

But via *title*.

Comment: Well... Have you tried the obvious xpath `'//*[@title="Havai 30"]'`???

Comment: That worked! With `[0]` at ending. Was getting list.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am looking site."*? It seems incomprehensible.

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*

Comment: *"I am looking site."* may refer to using the web developer tools in a web browser to look at the HTML source for a web site. For example, *"Inspector"* in Firefox (menu *Tools* → *Browser Tools* → *Web Developer Tools*).

Comment: Or if the "Tools" menu is hidden : `Alt` + `T`. Or keyboard shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` to open *Web Developer Tools*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like [barak manos said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363966/find-and-click-element-by-title-python-selenium#comment39549041_25363966), the answer was:

```
'//*[@title="Havai 30"]'
```

With [0] at ending, case it was list.

Comment: What do you mean by *"case it was list"*? It seems incomprehensible.

Comment: *"in case it was a list"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```py
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Havai 30"]').click()
```

This will work for me like you said.

Comment: From [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002313/selenium-finding-elements-by-class-name-in-python#comment128785684_30025430): *"`find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` are removed in Selenium 4.3.0. Use `find_element` instead."*.

Comment: It may be [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056864/selenium-by-xpath-what-to-import/73057414#73057414) `find_element(By.XPATH, ...)`, with import "`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`".

Answer (score 5):

For [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29):

```
String title = "SOME TITLE";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title^='" + title + "']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Havai 30"]').click()
```

** Make sure you include the starting and ending square brackets!

Answer (score -1):

For me it works with the [page object pattern](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@title='Havai 30']")
WebElement imHavai;
```