# Until/WebDriverWait throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Based on every answer and piece of documentation I've seen, the following should wait for the element at xpath `path`:

```
delay = some amount of time way longer than I know is needed
```

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay, ignored_exceptions=NoSuchElementException)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)))
```

but no matter what I do it always throws a `NoSuchElementException` *immediately* after getting the url. And before anyone marks this as a duplicate or calls me out on it, I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858687/cant-find-element-in-selenium-by-id-name-or-link-text-or-webdriverwait-no-s) answer and although the element I'm looking for is in some kind of wrapper, I got the same problem when trying the above looking for that wrapper instead (also it works if I just provide a normal `sleep` call instead of the `Expected Condition` stuff which makes me think I don't need to manually enter into the wrapper). What's the point of having a function for waiting for an element to be loaded that doesn't wait until the element is loaded? Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I use this java code for similar situations:

```
private Wait<WebDriver> staleWait = new FluentWait<>(getDriver())
        .withTimeout(WAIT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(POLLING_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
        .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);


protected WebElement visibilityOf(WebElement webElement) {
    staleWait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) webDriver -> {
        try {
            return element(webElement).isDisplayed();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ne) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return element(webElement);
}
```