# Python Selenium - Find and click element by title

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to login a website to web scrape its content with Selenium. The site has a virtual keyboard where the user inputs the password and I want to simulate the click on this keyboard.

https://www.rico.com.vc/

Inspecting the site, that's the part where the keyboard is generated (the position of each key is randomly generated by a JavaScript, but that part is OK):

```
<div class="password-buttons">
 <button class="button orange rounded" onclick="AddPsitions('8|9'); return false;" title="5 ou 3">
  <span class="login-number">5</span>
  <span class="login-or">ou</span>
  <span class="login-number">3</span>
 </button>
 <button class="button orange rounded" onclick="AddPsitions('6|7'); return false;" title="8 ou 2">
  <span class="login-number">8</span>
  <span class="login-or">ou</span>
  <span class="login-number">2</span>
 </button>
 <button class="button orange rounded" onclick="AddPsitions('4|5'); return false;" title="0 ou 6">
  <span class="login-number">0</span>
  <span class="login-or">ou</span>
  <span class="login-number">6</span>
 </button>
```

To simulate the click I'm doing the following (I also tried "//*[@title='0 ou 6']", without the '.'):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@title='0 ou 6']").click()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "webScrape_Rico.py", line 59, in <module>
 browser.find_element_by_xpath(a).click()
 File "/home/luciano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "/home/luciano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/home/luciano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/luciano/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: {" errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression \".//*[@title='0 ou 6']\" because of the following error:\nError: TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"109","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:60775","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"8ddb4f90-f6e6-11e6-9eb0-4ba40f4453e7\", \"value\": \"\\\".//*[@title='0 ou 6']\\\"\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8ddb4f90-f6e6-11e6-9eb0-4ba40f4453e7/element"}}
```

I saw this options here: [Find and click element by title Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363966/find-and-click-element-by-title-python-selenium)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The XPath `//button[@title='7 ou 8']` is working for me. You can use `$x()` to test XPaths in the Chrome browser, e.g. `$x("//button[@title='7 ou 8']")`. It will help you find the right locator faster.

Answer (score 0):

The title for those buttons is changing every time you open the site, so you can't use it to locate the buttons. I suggest you locate all the buttons using partial `onclick` attribute into list and use indexes to click on them

To make sure the elements are visible before clicking on them you can use explicit wait with [expected_conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
buttons = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@onclick, 'AddPsitions')]")))
buttons[0].click()
buttons[1].click()
#...
```

Comment: I'm treating this question about the buttons changing every time. Anyway, I tried your way and got this error: [...] selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: {"errorMessage":"SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12" [...]

Comment: But I tried a different approach: `buttons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='button orange rounded']")` and I'm able to find the buttons but I got this error now: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"` Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @lucianoaraujo Edited my answer. By the way, the xpath `"//button[@class='button orange rounded']"` doesn't find one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I still not able to click the element by the title, but I found a workaround finding the element to click via its 'class', not 'title'.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'button orange rounded')]")
```

And then clicking the element with index:

```
a[click].click()
```

I was also having the following problem:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

And that was happening because I was not selecting the keyboard first.
Since selenium literally simulates the user actions, I first have to select the virtual keyboard, so selenium can "see" the keys:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").click()
```

Thanks for all the help!