# How to use selenium to click on this button?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to use `selenium` to click on the expand button on this [webpage](http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Drift.html), which is the plus symbol.

[image]

Below is the page source of that elements:

```
<header>
<ol class="map">
    <li class="parent"><a href="../index.html" class="main">Random</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="index.html" class="main">16. Brownian Motion</a></li>
    <li class="child"><a href="Standard.html" class="main" title="Standard Brownian Motion">1</a></li>
    <li class="current">2</li>
    <li class="child"><a href="Bridge.html" class="main" title="The Brownian Bridge">3</a></li>
    <li class="child"><a href="Geometric.html" class="main" title="Geometric Brownian Motion">4</a></li>
    <li class="details"><button type="button" title="Expand Details" onclick="expandDetails(true);"><img src="../icons/Plus.png" alt="Expand" /></button></li>
    <li class="details"><button type="button" title="Contract Details" onclick="expandDetails(false);"><img src="../icons/Minus.png" alt="Contract" /></button></li>
</ol>
```

I think the keys lie in the last 2 lines:

```
<li class="details"><button type="button" title="Expand Details" onclick="expandDetails(true);"><img src="../icons/Plus.png" alt="Expand" /></button></li>
<li class="details"><button type="button" title="Contract Details" onclick="expandDetails(false);"><img src="../icons/Minus.png" alt="Contract" /></button></li>
```

I read on [4. Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), but could not find an appropriate method.

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

Could you please shed me some lights on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though below x path is not that good but click is happening on the button.

you hv not shared any code to refer , check if below lines can help you..

its in python so just modify if you are working on some other language..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

opt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()

opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe",options=opt)
driver.get("http://www.randomservices.org/random/brown/Drift.html")

# Wait for page to be loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/header/h2')))
time.sleep(1) # just to ensure element is properly loaded

plus_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/ol/li[7]/button')
plus_button.click()
# you can use Action chain as well for click
time.sleep(4)
minus_button  = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/ol/li[8]/button')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(minus_button).pause(1).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated help! These two lines `plus_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/ol/li[7]/button')` and `plus_button.click()` are keys :))

Comment: it will not work when you have more items in the list, the order (7, 8) might change.
Here is the answer to find elements by title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363966/find-and-click-element-by-title-python-selenium/

Comment: @LinhNguyen - Check the HTML of the page by link in the question , there are 2 elements which have same title i dont see that is covered in the link you shared ,,  all LI has same Class and there is no ID or Name attribute,, i have already mentioned that this is not a good path as page built is like that.

Comment: @HietshKumar you can combine (className + title) in the xpath